# VS Code - size of description popup

Tags: window, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I am creating a snippet for VS Code with long descriptions.
I have noticed that the description popup window in VS Code has a scrollbar, but it would be greater if I can enlarge the window? Is it possible?

Comment: VSCode 1.80 should allow *all* popup to be resizable. (June 2023). See my [edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64641253/6309).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VSCode 1.51 (Oct. 2020) should add (part of) that feature with:

### [Resizable suggestions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/b90c7662cebb51d859506135a03f1ff459f1c743/release-notes/v1_51.md#resizable-suggestions)

> This milestone, we've made several improvements to the suggestions UI. First and foremost: it can now be resized! Drag the sides or corners to resize the control.
>
> [image: Resizable Suggestions control -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_51/suggest-drag.gif]
>
> <sup>Theme: [GitHub Light](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=github.github-vscode-theme), Font: FiraCode</sup>
>
> The size of the suggestions list will be saved and restored across sessions.
> The size of the details pane is only saved per session, since the size tends to be more variable.
> Also, the `editor.suggest.maxVisibleSuggestions` setting has become obsolete.

---

As noted by [Jan M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10571911/jan-m) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638328/vs-code-size-of-description-popup/64641253#comment114894292_64641253), this only  allows resizing the **suggestion window, not the popup window**.
Feature allowing to resize the popup window is not yet implemented:
[`microsoft/vscode` issue 14165](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/14165): "Feature request: configure tooltip max width".

That ticket has been completed for VSCode 1.80 (June 2023), with

- [PR 178811](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/178811): "Adding type ResizableContentWidget - using it for the content hover widget"
- [PR 185540](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/185540): "Adding the resizable content hover code without the persistance mechanism"

[image: resizable hover]

It is available with [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) today.

Comment: This allows resizing only the suggestion window, not the popup window. Feature allowing to resize the popup window [still is not implemented](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/14165).

Comment: @JanM. Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 12):

This is possible now with the [Custom CSS and JS Loader extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css).

---

#### 1. Install extension

[Custom CSS and JS Loader extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css)

#### 2. Set permissions

- **macOS**

  - VS Code: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron`
  - VS Code Insiders: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Applications/Visual Studio Code - Insiders.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron`
- **Linux**: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/share/code`

#### 3. Create CSS override file

`touch ~/.vscode-custom.css`:

```css
/* suggest-widget size */

.monaco-editor .suggest-widget.docs-side {
  width: 1000px;
}

.monaco-editor .suggest-widget.docs-side > .details {
  width: 60%;
  max-height: 800px !important;
}

.monaco-editor .suggest-widget.docs-side > .tree {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}

/* parameter-hints-widget */

.editor-widget.parameter-hints-widget.visible {
  max-height: 800px !important;
}

.monaco-editor .parameter-hints-widget > .wrapper {
  max-width: 1000px;
}

/* editor-hover */

.monaco-editor-hover .monaco-editor-hover-content {
  max-width: 1000px;
}
```

### Apply CSS file path to `settings.json`

```json
{
  "vscode_custom_css.imports": ["file:///Users/yourusername/.vscode-custom.css"],
  "vscode_custom_css.policy": true
}
```

#### 4. Restart VSCode

- Restart VSCode
- Ignore "VSCode is corrupt errors_

  - You can choose to suppress these forever
- Run command "Reload Custom CSS and JS"

Answer (score 8):

No, that's not possible currently. Sometimes text even wraps in such a popup window, which makes it difficult to read. Certainly something that needs improvement.

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: ok, i have ask for a new feature.  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/29126

Comment: Why did you unaccept my answer? It was correct at that time. If we remove all acceptance for solutions that are now outdated, half of the SO answsers would need to be demoted.

Comment: @MikeLischke Which would be a good thing?

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely possible with [Customize UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui) + [Monkey Patch](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.monkey-patch) extensions.

Install them and then add the following to your settings.json:

`"customizeUI.stylesheet": {".monaco-hover-content, .hover-contents span, .parameter-hints-widget div.code, .parameter-hints-widget div.docs": "font-size: 12px !important"}`

Don't forget to reload the window to apply the changes!

Works like a charm for me with VS Code `1.63.2`