# How to remove detail IntelliSense in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, editor

I use vscode, i think most of us use vscode, vscode is awesome tool but sometime it annoying at same time, it happen to me when i see this pop up when i move to new laptop
[image]

I need IntelliSense but not this detail, it block my view many time why i'm typing, how can i disable this? (not disable IntelliSense, just this detail)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44638328 might work for you

Answer (score 0):

Those are parameter hints. Set `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false` to disable them

After disabling them, you can still manually trigger them using the `editor.action.triggerParameterHints` command

There is no way to disable just one section of the parameter hints

Comment: Thank for your answer