# How to change Parameter hint box size in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How I can change the parameter hint size box In VScode so I can see more parameters?
[image]

Comment: That's not possible currently. There is an existing GitHub issue and another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638328/vs-code-size-of-description-popup) talks about it too. There's an answer that suggests using some plugin to achieve this.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick thanks dude how i can archive the post?

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution using [Custom CSS Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css)

```css
.parameter-hints-widget {
  max-height: 4000px !important;
}
.phwrapper {
  max-width: 4000px !important;
  max-height: 4000px !important;
}
.phwrapper.monaco-scrollable-element {
  max-width: 4000px !important;
  max-height: 4000px !important;
}
```